# Is there a way to make Postmaster receiver email dynamic?

Tags: postmaster

I have a channel called `foo` which is tied up to a member via [Safecracker Registration](https://objectivehtml.com/safecracker-registration).

The `foo` channel has a field for an email.

When someone edits a `foo` channel entry, I want to send an email to the owner of the channel entry.

Is there way to in the Parcels/Hooks so that the email can be sent to the user via the email field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah this is pretty standard functionality.

1. Create a new parcel
2. Your To Email would be `{member:email}`, which grabs the email of the entry's author
3. Set the entry trigger to "Edit"

Here is a screenshot to be 100% clear.

[image]

Comment: I think this answers my needs. But for the sake of discussion, lets say I want to get an email from channel entries data. What if, for example, you need to set a different email from the member's own(like "company_email")?

Comment: Say, @arvinsim, did you manage to figure out how to send an email to an address in a channel field?